# vuejs - rendering class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview

This is my `iview Message` function that renders popup message.

```
    this.$Message.info({
                render: h => {
                    return h('div', {class:"red"}, [
                        'This is created by ',
                        h('span', 'render'),
                        ' function'
                    ])
                }
            });
```

The CSS

```
.red{
  color:red;
  background:blue;
}
```

However, I need to render a class for the `span` instead of the whole `div`.

Any ways to render only the `span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `class` object in the `span` element instead of the `div` element.

```js
this.$Message.info({
  render: h => {
    return h("div", 
    [
      "This is created by ", 
      h("span", {class : "red" }, "render function ")
    ])
  }
});
```

Example :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => {
    return h("div", 
    [
      "This is created by ", 
      h("span", {class : "red" }, "render function ")
    ])
  }
})
```

```css
.red {
  color:red;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I need to apply the css for the word in the `span` only , instead of the whole sentence

Answer (score 0):

class should be an array, not a string:

```js
h('div', {class: ['red']})
```

[Vue docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#vnode-props-format)